# HTML Javascript button not working

Tags: javascript, html, button, if-statement

Hello friends I am new to learning HTML I am trying to make a basic website but I can't get a button which changes the sites background and the button text value to work please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function lightsOff()
      {
        if (document.getElementbyID("btnLights").value == "Lights Off") {
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#151515";
          document.getElementbyID("btnLights").value = "Lights On";
        }
        else {
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
          document.getElementbyID("btnLights").value = "Lights Off";
        }
      }
    </script>

  <center>

    <input type="button" id="btnLights" onclick="lightsOff()" value="Lights Off"></input>
  </center>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm sure its just something silly but I am new and need help!

Comment: The right way is: `getElementById`. Javascript is case sensitive. You're probably getting errors in the console. Check it.

Comment: This was it! Thanks so much I shouldn't have copied the code from a different answer, I'm not using anything with a console just notepad.

Comment: No probs. I've posted an answer.

Comment: I recommend finding a good IDE or Programmers notepad.  It helps find errors such as that :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, 
Just replace `getElementbyID` with  `getElementById`

Here you have a [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/ElUVekO/1/)

Answer (score 0):

1) `getElementById` is the proper syntax, not `ID`

2) Not sure on this, but you may need your script to be underneath your HTML elements, so that they exist when it is parsed by the browser for the first time. Someone can correct me on this though if it's inaccurate.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case sensitive. Just replace `getElementbyID` with `getElementById` and things will just work.

Answer (score 0):

you have done just smaller mistake of spelling.

here :
    document.getElementbyID  //your code

correct syntex is :
    document.getElementById  // correct code

replace "document.getElementbyID" by this  "document.getElementById"